# SensorEventListener and Timer-thread using shared Vector

Tags: java, android, multithreading, vector

What is the best way to handle competing threads that are reading data from a vector?

I'm trying to write an android app where I'm trying to read sensor data periodically and write it to a file and then upload the file to a remote server.

What I do as the first step, I register the SensorEventListener for each sensor and then, whenever sensor values change, I push new values to a `Vector()`. Here `data` is a vector of user defined object.

```
@Override

// when sensor value is changed, this method will be called.

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  synchronized (this){
    Datapoint dp=new Datapoint(event.sensor.getType(),event.values);
    data.add(dp);
  }
}
```

As the next step I use a `Timer` object to periodically read off data from the `data` vector and send it to a remote server.

```
class calculateSensorData extends TimerTask {
      public synchronized void run() {
       for (Datapoint item : data) {
              //use data    
       }
       data.clear();
     }
}
```

The main problem is when I try to access the data vector inside the `TimerTask` I get `java.util.ConcurrentModficiationException`.

I think this is because both the sensor listener thread and timer thread are trying to update/modify the shared Vector at the same time.

I got around the problem by un-registering the listeners at the start of the `Timer` task. But that not a good solution.

Any other way to accomplish this without un-registering and re-registering all sensor listeners each time the `Timer` fires.

Comment: arent Vectors synchronized..

Comment: That is what I thought too. But don't know why this is happening. (For redundancy I even tried the synchronized methods at shown in the post)